# Image Processing of Function Graph

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I would like to detect these points in this graph , also I wanted to detect the lines , 
[image]

I searched for edge detection and corner detection (such as Harris Corner Detector ), but I don't know how to handle such graph , I only need to know a sudo algorithm , or steps of going through such problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Detect the vertices - segment by color( r>>max(g,b) ) and then apply the median or minimum filter of the appropriate size, or simply binary erode few times. Then just label the remaining connected blobs.
2. Detect the lines - use the simplified Hough Transform. Basicaly, draw a virtual line from the center of each vertix to all others and count the red pixels along the line. If there are plenty of them - the line exists, otherwise the two vertices are not connected.

Something like that:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.misc import imshow, imsave, imread
from scipy.ndimage import filters, morphology, measurements
from skimage.draw import line

img = imread("laGK6.jpg")

r = img[:,:, 0]
g = img[:,:, 1]
b = img[:,:, 2]

mask = (r.astype(np.float)-np.maximum(g,b) ) > 20

mask2 = morphology.binary_erosion(mask)
mask2 = morphology.binary_erosion(mask2)
mask2 = morphology.binary_erosion(mask2)
mask2 = morphology.binary_erosion(mask2)

mask2 = morphology.binary_dilation(mask2)

label, numfeatures = measurements.label(mask2)

mc = measurements.center_of_mass(mask2, label, range(1,numfeatures+1) )

mask3 = np.zeros_like(mask2)

for p in mc:
    mask3[p[0], p[1]]=255




arr = range(numfeatures)

connections=[]
for i in range( numfeatures):
    arr.remove(i)
    for j in arr:
        rr,cc = line(mc[i][0], mc[i][1], mc[j][0], mc[j][1])
        mask3[rr,cc]=255
        ms = np.sum(mask[rr,cc]).astype(np.float)/len(rr)
        if ms > 0.9:
            connections.append((i,j))


print "vertices: ", mc
print "connections: ", connections
```

This outputs the following:

> vertices:  [(76.551724137931032, 288.72413793103448),
>   (76.568181818181813, 613.61363636363637), (138.72727272727272,
>   126.04545454545455), (139.33333333333334, 450.33333333333331), (265.18181818181819, 207.5151515151515), (264.96666666666664,
>   369.53333333333336), (265.41379310344826, 694.51724137931035), (265.51724137931035, 45.379310344827587), (327.57692307692309,
>   532.42307692307691)] 
>   connections:  [(0, 4), (0, 5), (1, 6), (1, 8), (2, 4), (2, 7), (3, 5), (3, 8)]

Answer (score 1):

I am also working on a project that detects shapes in a drawing. I am not sure if it will solve your problem as well but here is what I have done for such problems.
I am assuming that you need the value of X and Y coordinates of those edge points

- first thing you need is the X and Y values of the complete shape
- next inside a loop put an if condition saying "get this point if 
  `Y[i]<Y[i+1]` and `Y[i]<Y[i-1]`". point whose next and previous points have Y greater than the value of current Y.
  this condition will give you the X and Y values of the edge points.
  [image: this image will help you understand my point]
  Good Luck

Answer (score 1):

If the graph is always the same color, and the vertices are always marked with squares, you can threshold the image by its color to detect lines and vertices. Then look for connected sets of pixels whose width and height are exactly the ones you can just measure.